# Publish videos to youtube api unverified app

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have developed an app for a company that generates personalized videos and needs to publish them to Youtube. Everything works fine except I can't publish videos to youtube do to the following rules loop:

1. If your app is not validated (by google for authentication) it can't upload videos to youtube.
2. If you app is not public it can't be validated.

How can I exit the loop and publish the videos?

Note: the app needs to publish the videos to an account that is a @gmail account.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have miss understood something if you check the documentation for [Video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) at the top you will see the following

> All videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from **unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode**. To lift this restriction, each API project must undergo an audit to verify compliance with the Terms of Service. Please see the API Revision History for more details.

So you can upload videos to YouTube without your app being verified.  They will just be uploaded as private.

After consulting with my contact at google.  They cleared something up for us.

There is apparently a difference between `OAuth verification` and the `YouTube compliance audit`.  I assumed they were the same thing.

1. OAuth verification (requested through Google Cloud Console) This verifies your Oauth2 consent screen.
2. Compliance Audit (requested through [YouTube API form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)) this will give you the ability to post public videos.

So the team is correct you don't need to Oauth2 verify your app as it is used for internal project.   You do however need to go though the YouTube compliance audit which you need to do even if its an internal app.

Comment: I need the videos to be public.
I've already set the app to production and followed verification steps. However I always get a Request Denied.
The reason: "Since your app is for personal use, your project does not require verification."
Here is the infinite loop.

Comment: Email them back and tell them that you need the videos to be public.  Some of the people doing the verification don't realize that the YouTube api requires the app to be verified for public videos. Technically if you need public videos its not for personal use.   Although we may be arguing statics there.

Comment: I pinged someone on the auth team i sware i have been though this with them before.

Comment: Just sent an email specifying exactly that I need public videos, although I've expressed that already in other mails. Let's see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @Mateu check my update.  My contact came back with some very interesting clarifications.

Comment: Wow! I already had done this step to increase the quota! Just checked and I can publish public videos. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I had no idea ! i was so shocked myself.